# Why is enthalpy discussed exclusively as $\Delta H$ and doesn't make sense as just $H$

Tags: thermodynamics

For a chemical reaction, it is well-known that
$$\Delta H = H_{\text{products}} -H_{\text{reactants}}$$

Are we physically unable to determine an absolute $H$?

Comment: Why would you want to if, in practical situations, it is the change which matters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; since we are unable to determine an absolute energy $U$ and since enthalpy $H\equiv U+PV$, we are unable to determine an absolute enthalpy (or Helmholtz free energy or Gibbs free energy or chemical potential or anything that includes $U$).

Comment: I appreciate the edit suggestion; unfortunately, it changes the intended meaning.

Comment: thank you so very much, makes sense now